# mathtools brackets

Tags: mathtools

Using `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` I have defined a command to enclose expressions with parenthesis.

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{(}{)}
```

Now, I want to defined a command for a function

```
\newcommand{\myfunc}[1]{f\p{#1}}
```

Is there an easy way to pass the optional parameter from `\myfunc` to `\p` so that I can write `\myfunc[\Big]{x}`. I know I can use `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` to declare `\myfunc` from scratch but I was wondering if there was a way to make my definitions more modular.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{(}{)}
\newcommand{\myfunc}[1]{f\p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[\myfunc{x}\]
% How to make these work? Without breaking \myfunc{x}
% \[\myfunc[\Big]{x}\] 
% \[\myfunc*{x}\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `\myfunc` without arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{(}{)}
\newcommand{\myfunc}{f\p}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\myfunc{x} \\
\myfunc[\Big]{x} \\
\myfunc*{\frac{x}{2}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a lot easier to simply use `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`, which is build for this kind of constructions. Just use

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\myfunc[1]{f}{(}{)}{}{#1}
```

On the other hand, you you really **want** to use `\p`, then you'll need to manually parse the arguments using the `xparse` package, and then call `\p` in the appropriate manner using the detected options (you need to look for starred, optional in [] and mandatory, so in `xparse` you need to make a macro with an `s o m` 'signature').

Answer (score 2):

I defined a macro that inserts the optional argument before the `(` and `)`. The definition of the macro is made inside a local group so that once it exits, the effect of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is erased so it can be used again in the document.

I also added the solution that @campa and @daleif provided in the comments, which is much cleaner and less prone to errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p{(}{)}

\newcommand{\myfunc}[1]{f\p{#1}}

% Keeping my previous solution
\newcommand{\myotherfunc}[2][]{%
\begingroup% < Make the definition of \pp local to this group (thanks @campa)
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\pp{#1(}{#1)}
f\pp{#2}%
\endgroup%
}

% Easier, faster, cleaner solution by @campa and @daleif
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\myanotherfunc[1]{f}{(}{)}{}{#1}

\begin{document}
\[\myfunc{x}\]
% How to make these work? Without breaking \myfunc{x}
\[\myotherfunc[\Big]{x} \text{ and } \myotherfunc[\Big]{y}\]
\[\myanotherfunc[\Big]{x} \text{ and } \myanotherfunc[\Big]{y}\] 
% \[\myfunc*{x}\] 
\end{document}
```

I just couldn't understand the purpose of the starred version.

Comment: @campa `D=` I didn't think about this. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Campas comment above, it the best way to do this, simply use `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\p[1]{f}{(}{)}{}{#1}`, job done.